# Subclipse error -- Subversion Native Library not available

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I am getting the following message everytime the PHP project based on Subversion loads...

[image: Subversion Native Library not available.]

Obviously shown, the OS is a Mac OSX Mountain Lion.
I have also followed the instructions within the link, and it still appears at completely random times.
However, subversion actions seem to work fine.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that I followed the directions in there to the letter. This still appears.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From main menu, select

> Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN,

at right panel "*SVN interface*" zone.
You may find "*client*" is set to "*JavaHL(JNI) Not Available*".
Change it to "*SVNKit(Pure Java) SVNKit vx.x*"

Comment: +1..
I think this answer provides a more direct approach as to what should be done on eclipse->preferences to get the issue resolved. Thanks a ton m8!!!

Comment: In my opinion, this should be the accepted answer.  I used this answer to solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

Your error is that the library has been loaded in another classloader.  I can only guess you have some other Subversion plugin installed (so that you have more than one) and the other one has already loaded the library so it cannot be loaded again.

Aside from figuring that out and removing the other plugin, I would guess you can just install the SVNKit plugin and configure Subclipse to use it instead of JavaHL.  The SVNKit plugin is on the Subclipse update site.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have uninstalled the probable interrupting plugins but I still get the same error. However the funny thing is that SVN operations are totally fine. I can do the updates, checkouts and checkins / commits.
I shall perhaps look furthermore for any other plugins. SVNKit seems to be already installed.

Comment: If SVNKit is installed and JavaHL is not available, then Subclipse automatically uses SVNKit.  So that is probably why other stuff is working.  I use OSX, but am still on Lion.  I have not heard of general problems using Mountain Lion and cannot envision how class loading could be different.  It seems like there must be another plugin.

Comment: Thanks! @MarkPhippard! I think I might have to either live with it or attempt uninstalling SVNKit.

Comment: @MarkPhippard In Eclipse Photon, installing Subclipse along with the SVNKit package (at the same time!) still fails to auto-select the SVNKit implementation. You have to dismiss several dire warnings to get to the screen where you can tell Eclipse not to be stupid and use the only available SVN API.